# comparing two objects at different dates by database or algorithm

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, algorithm

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10418/1/0

I have a question of managing ranking of some objects in some rank charts at specif dates.

I have data for start date and end date. I want net effect column. how do I make it? its basically the change in position. e.g for A,  start date position was null. so it came to 1 rank. so +5.   for B, start=4, end=2 so 4-2= +2 /\ rise

1. Are database queries a better solution or java code for this (I do have the data in database though).
2. Can any one show the code and the query (which ever way is preferred). (I would appreciate both approaches or at-least strategies). How to create the NET EFFECT.

**The results I want to show:**

```
    RANK        NET EFFECT      object at END date      object at START date
    1           A   +5 /\           A                   C
    2           B   +2 /\           B                   D
    3           Z   +2 /\           Z                   E
    4           D   -2 \/           D                   B
    5           E   -2 \/           E                   Z
                C   -5 \/           -                   -
```

---

Further information: **EDIT - 1**

A is not before B. A is at #1 at certain date and no where (within 1 to 5) at an other date. start date and end date are just 2 distinct dates at which a,b,c,d,e..z had some position/rank number.

the a,b,c,d,..z are in no order but only have som #number of rank with them. each #number/rank + ABCD..Z combination is different at each specific date.

A java Comparator will just sort the objects. not producing a net rank rise/fall

Example data that I have:

**DB table:**

```
    RANK        date        object      
    1           x           A               
    2           x           B               
    3           x           Z              
    4           x           D              
    5           x           E   


    RANK        date            object
    1           y                C
    2           y                D
    3           y                E
    4           y                B
    5           y                Z
```

Comment: For each object, get the previous ranking and compare it to the current ranking. The difference is the net effect.

Comment: yes. that sounds simple and was exactly what I had in mind. but making a list out with a proper solution as shown in "results" is an issue. secondly, some elements might not be in one date but be present in another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10418/29

```
  SELECT t1.topper_position
       , t0.app_store_id
       , COALESCE(t2.topper_position, 6) - COALESCE(t1.topper_position, 6) AS delta2
       , COALESCE(t1.fetch_date, t2.fetch_date) AS cur_date
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT app_store_id
            FROM crawler_2_application_details
           WHERE topper_position <= 5
             AND fetch_date IN ('2014-04-19 19:56:24', '2014-04-18 19:56:24')
         ) AS t0
    LEFT JOIN crawler_2_application_details AS t1
      ON t1.fetch_date = '2014-04-19 19:56:24' 
     AND t0.app_store_id = t1.app_store_id 
    LEFT JOIN crawler_2_application_details AS t2
      ON t2.fetch_date = '2014-04-18 19:56:24' 
     AND t0.app_store_id = t2.app_store_id 
   ORDER BY t1.topper_position IS NULL
          , t1.topper_position
  ;
```

Comment: isn't this the better way? although this does not entertains C ? sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10418/25/0 how to entertain C ?

Comment: Notice I handled your C issue, where C is no longer in the top N, but was in the top N for the prior date.  The other approach, while fine, did not handle that case.  A full outer join could also have been used.